# ValueError: too many values to unpack in python

Tags: python

I am running the follow script and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/MySmplePythonApplication/src/Test2.py", line 22, in <module> print smooth(array) 
File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/MySmplePythonApplication/src/Test2.py", line 10, in smooth dx, dy= array.shape 
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

array = np.array(Image.open('noisy.tif'))

#Apply a 3x3 mean filter to my image array.

def smooth(array, window=3.0):
    dx, dy = array.shape
    new_array = np.copy(array)
    edgex = int(math.floor(window / 2.0))
    edgey = int(math.floor(window / 2.0))

    for i in range(dx):
        for j in range(dy):
            window_array = array[max(i - edgex, 0):min(i + edgex + 1, dx),
                                 max(j - edgey, 0):min(j + edgey + 1, dy)]
            new_array[i, j] = window_array.mean()
    return new_array

print smooth(array)
```

I know that there are too many topics about that but still could not fix it.

Comment: Seems like `array.shape` is not a pair.

Comment: A complete trace back is needed in order to suggest a solution to the problem.

Comment: KobiK because I am newbie in python by saying traceback you mean?
@NikolaDimitroff indeed I "add" dz and keep only in my solution dx dy but that's wrong. Why I am not having a pair in a 2D pictures?

Comment: We need to know the full error text, including the line where the error happens.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/MySmplePythonApplication/src/Test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    print smooth(array)
  File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/MySmplePythonApplication/src/Test2.py", line 10, in smooth
    dx, dy= array.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dx, dy = array.shape
```

array.shape returns more than 2 values and has thus more than 2 dimensions.

Here is why:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/imread.html

"The return value A is an array containing the image data. If the file contains a grayscale image, A is an M-by-N array. If the file contains a truecolor image, A is an M-by-N-by-3 array. For TIFF files containing color images that use the CMYK color space, A is an M-by-N-by-4 array. See TIFF in the Format-Specific Information section for more information."

The third dimension is Red, Green and Blue values.

Comment: I have a 2D image. Printing array.shape I get (269, 562, 3)